# Mysql Import *.sql with creating the database

Tags: mysql, database, import

I have dir with a lot of `.sql` files. I want to import them all at once when creating the database. Is it possible without doing it one-by-one?

I already tried

```
mysql -u user -p Database < *.sql
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it so:

```
cat *.sql | mysql -u user -p Database
```

OR

```
cat *.sql >/tmp/all.sql
mysql -u user -p Database < /tmp/all.sql
rm /tmp/all.sql
```

Comment: `cat` is the solution here as it will combine all the `.sql` files together into one.

Comment: i can't do that because  Database each sql file is a diffrent database

Comment: You can put the name of each Database in the File at the top with USE DBNAME; So do you must not select one at the commandline

Comment: You mus put one line in each sql file with USE DATABASENAME; to select a DB whenthe sql is executed

Comment: i got your idea, but isn't there any other way since they more than 100databases ?

Comment: no, there is no other way. How the Database find out the right Schema (without magic). So you must specify the Databases.

Comment: When you import file per file, you also must declare the Database Name